# Javascript array containing arrays but length is 0

Tags: javascript

```
var food = ["fruit=apple", "fruit=banana", "drink=cola"];
var vars = [];
for(var i = 0; i < food.length; i++)
{
    var key = food[i].substring(0, food[i].indexOf("="));
    if (vars[key] == undefined){
        vars[key] = [];
    }
    vars[key].push(food[i].toLowerCase().split("=")[1]);
}
console.log(vars);
console.log(vars.length);
```

The output from the above code will output this. But the problem is that the length: 0. I don't understand how that is even possible, because you can clearly see that the array containing [fruit: Array(2), drink: Array(1)]. But still it says length: 0;

[image: The output of vars and vars.length]

I want to loop through the vars array with a for loop, but I can't because I cannot use the vars.length in my for loop.

Or maybe there is a other way to loop through the vars anny suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What should the length be? 2, because of the number of keys, 3, because of the total number of items, or something else?

Comment: yes it need to be 2. I also need the keywords to be the index so if say food[fruit].length I want to see how many items there are in the fruit array that is inside of the food array.

Comment: Right, so just use an object `{}`, and use @hsz's solution to get the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your `vars` array as an object. Arrays don't have literal keys. With your approach, you can count your values using:

```
Object.values(vars).length
```